# Elixir macro with guard clause not working as expected for negative values

Tags: elixir

Why is the following Elixir macro not working for negative values?

The code is really simple, nothing really fancy, only one macro with some simple guard clauses:

```
defmodule IntegerChecker do
  defmacro is_negative_or_zero(number)
    when is_integer(number) and number <= 0, do: true
  
  defmacro is_negative_or_zero(number)
    when is_integer(number), do: false
end
```

```
> import IntegerChecker

> is_negative_or_zero(0)
true

> is_negative_or_zero(1)
false

> is_negative_or_zero(20)
false

> is_negative_or_zero(-1)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in IntegerChecker.is_negative_or_zero/1
    expanding macro: IntegerChecker.is_negative_or_zero/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are defining a macro and not a function, the argument going to be passed is the AST, not the value.

- functions: passing values, at runtime
- macros: passing AST, at compile time

So `number` is going to be the AST for `-1`, which you can check using [`quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2):

```elixir
iex(1)> quote do: -1
{:-, [context: Elixir, imports: [{1, Kernel}, {2, Kernel}]], [1]}
iex(2)> quote do: 1
1
```

Unlike `1`, the AST representing `-1` is a tuple, not the integer itself.

In your case, you probably want to either use a regular function (if you want to raise in non-number cases), or a [guard](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defguard/1) (which won't raise):

```elixir
defguard is_negative_or_zero(number) when is_integer(number) and number <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the answer provided by @sabiwara is absolutely correct, your goal is still achievable with a macro, you just need to properly pattern-match.

```elixir
defmodule IntegerChecker do
  defmacro is_negative_or_zero(0), do: true

  defmacro is_negative_or_zero({:-, _, [number]})
    when is_integer(number), do: true
  
  defmacro is_negative_or_zero(number)
    when is_integer(number), do: false
end
```